# How to move Landscape clients to a new server without duplicating

Tags: server, landscape

We had to upgrade our Landscape server. The process we followed was to install a new Ubuntu server, install the new version of Landscape, backup the database on the old server and import to the new server. This process has worked but I am stuck with how to handle the clients connecting with the new server without generating a new registration.
I have copied the new server certificate and updated the client.conf file with the new server details. But when the client connects to the server it shows as a new registration.
This means I will have to go through and approve 100s of new client registrations and match them to the existing registration.
Is there any way to do this more easily?